# JS Dynamic Object within Object within Object... traversing

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, nested

**Context**

I have a set of JSON data stored as an object. I want to "Group" this data by a particular attribute. This works. But then I want the ability to further group the already grouped data even more. This is where I get stuck. The process I'm following might be totally wrong, so if you have a better way to group, and further group JSON data, please say.

**Process**

Take the `data` object, and replace it with a new object which contains `groupLevel`, `filter`, and a new `data` object, and so on and so on, until all grouping has been finalised.

**Problem**

How do I traverse this structure, target specifically the lowest `data` object, create the new grouping as below (I can do this), and then return the whole lot as a brand new structure, to be used in the rest of the code. The issue is in keeping the structure intact, whilst being able to make the changes at the lowest level.

original data structure:

```
Object:
- attr1:"val1"
- attr2:"val2"
- attr3:"val3"
- attr{n}:"val{n}"
```

grouped data structure:

```
Object:
- groupLevel:1
- filter:"attr2"
- data:Object:
  - "val2a": Array[18]
    - 0: Object
      - attr1:"val1"
      - attr2:"val2"
      - attr3:"val3"
      - attr4:"val4"
      - attr{n}:"val{y}"
    - 1: Object
    - 2: Object
    - 3: Object
    - {n}: Object
  - "val2b": Array[15]
  - "val2c": Array[6]
  - "val2d": Array[3]
  - "val2e": Array[2]
```

grouped grouped data structure (at a guess, as I dont know how to get to this stage, hence this SO question):

```
Object:
- groupLevel:2
- filter:"attr2"
- data:Object:
  - "val-hdfgdhdd": Array[20]
  - "val-hdfgddfd": Array[10]
  - "val-hdgggggg": Array[22]
    - groupLevel:1
    - filter:"attr2"
    - data:Object:
      - "val2a": Array[18]
        - 0: Object
          - attr1:"val1"
          - attr2:"val2"
          - attr3:"val3"
          - attr4:"val4"
          - attr{n}:"val{y}"
        - 1: Object
        - 2: Object
        - 3: Object
        - {n}: Object
      - "val2b": Array[15]
      - "val2c": Array[6]
      - "val2d": Array[3]
      - "val2e": Array[2]
```

I am able to Group 1 level, but now that I am trying to group a grouped dataset, I then I realised, as shown below, I am 'discarding' the higher levels each time I drill down, so whilst I get my lowest `data` object, after I then replace the final 'data' object with another grouped level, I have lost all the levels above. but... how do I keep the whole structure and make the new grouping?

Current failed code snippet to drill down this new structure:

```js
if(baseObject['groupLevel']) {
  while (baseObject['groupLevel'] != 1) {
    baseObject['groupLevel']++;
    baseObject = baseObject['data'];
  }
  // once out of the loop, I 'should' be left with a baseObject which I can further group.
} else {
  // baseObject with no grouping, group the data, and store it in the structure shown above, giving it a level of 1.
}
```

Updated the question based on user feedback on incomplete structure example. By the way, I might be doing this completely wrong. if anyone can suggest a better way to group JSON data, please say.

Comment: The way you have written the grouped data structure it doesn't seem like you've assigned it any filtered properties? Am I misunderstanding? It would look like this in JSON? http://pastebin.com/uCg8D1Dn

Comment: Ah yes, made a mistake there. The structure should have the filter level in there too, I'll amend the question now. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't quite follow the relationship between your initial `data` object and your grouped `data` object. How do you know which attributes of your initial object go into which grouped object? What is the logic you are applying?

Comment: The logic is a guess, I dont know the best way to do this, so im trying a few things. From further research I found I might be better off using underscore.js to group, rather than reinventing the wheel. But I then still need to work out how to iterate through this in the best way to output the data on the page. That part may have to be a new SO question if it comes to it, to avoid off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you want to provide some way to browse/filter through large list of objects. In that case, consider combining grouping with filtering, preferably server-side.

If data set is of moderate size then your approach might work well. I have created [proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/jeade8u3/1/) and if you inspect objects dumped in console window, they look similar to your structures. The idea is to have `GroupedData` class which can be used instead of array of objects. Constructor takes original data and builds `groups` property leaving original data intact.

```
function GroupedData(data, prop) {
    var self = this;
    self.groups = {};
    self.filter = prop;
    data.forEach(function(o, i) {
        var pval = o[prop];
        if(!self.groups.hasOwnProperty(pval)) {
            self.groups[pval] = [];
        }
        self.groups[pval].push(o);
    });
}
GroupedData.prototype.thenBy = function(prop) {
    var self = this;
    function processTree(branch) {
        branch = branch || self;
        for(var parentProp in branch.groups) {
            if(branch.groups.hasOwnProperty(parentProp) ) {
                var pg = branch.groups[parentProp];
                if(pg instanceof GroupedData) {
                    processTree(pg);
                } else {
                    var sub = new GroupedData(pg, prop);
                    branch.groups[parentProp] = sub;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    processTree();
    return this;
}
```

This code does not keep track of level but it can be easily recorded.

Obviously, you have to build UI for grouping. As soon as the user applies grouping, create new GroupedData instance (first level) or just apply `.thenBy()`. When displaying list of objects, you should check if it is `instanceof GroupedData` and render appropriate UI.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I was trying to achieve. Im glad you understood as it was hard to explain and many others struggled to decipher the problem. Have not been able to try this yet, as I found underscore.js before I saw your answer. But I will keep it in mind in case underscore.js doesnt match my needs. At the very least, you have a good answer for others coming across this issue. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, but still open to others to provide input. This is not necesarily the "right answer" but it offers a path to follow to continue.

I found from the comments that my logic above was not making sense, and to be honest, I was struggling to find out it would work properly.

**Underscore.js**
Hence, the best solution I can find is to use something like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) and its [GroupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) function, to achieve the same result, without reinventing the wheel.

Thoughts?

Comment: Russell, you still haven't explained how you get from `original data structure` to `grouped data structure`. If it is hard to explain with words, then put an example with REAL data (`valn` is imprecise : is it a value, an object?): give SEVERAL inputs, and the corresponding expected outputs for the first grouping. For now, we see a `filter` property, but we have no idea what kind of filtering you want to do. Filter are rejecting/acceping values in relation with a boolean predicate. What is that predicate? If the first step is clear, the recursive steps should follow naturally.

Comment: I can understand its not clear, as the more I look at it, the more holes there were with the example structure I gave. Thats the problem though, this is all a proof of concept, I dont know how it should look. Hence this SO question. In its simplest terms, I have JSON data that I need to group by column1, then group again by column2 and further if need be. the question is how to do this and how to store this within an object or array, and still be able to keep a good data structure

Comment: Since finding underscore.js and the other answer from nrodic that was given I feel there is enough to go on without going back and trying to fix the data structure in the question.